# when music pause, Which sensor does galaxy S3(or S4 ….) use?

Tags: android, sensors, galaxy

When music is played in GalaxyS3 (or S4, etc…), if phone is filled upside down, the music is stopped.
at this moment, which sensor exactly sensing the "flipping".

Comment: Multiple sensors can be used for this. For example the accelerometer or the gyroscope. But do you have an actual question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample Code to detect phone flipping could look like this: 
http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/02/detect-phone-flipping.html

So basically you should use the accelerometer of your smartphone and place your custom code to  onSensorChanged

Answer (score 0):

The accelerometer of the phones can be used to determine the orientation of the phone (when it does not move). This sensor is used to change the screen orientation when you rotate your device, and also to stop the music when you flip it.

For more information on the sensors in your Android device, see: [Sensors overview](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html)

Comment: thanks, but Are you sure..?
Is thers any offical document?
I wanna control not to pause when I flip the phone.

Comment: It can be turned off in the settings in the S3...